# Teamviewer: VPN not working on Windows 7 client

Tags: vpn, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer for accessing a Windows 7 machine, VPN driver is installed.

**the problem:**
with the machine's firewall enabled, VPN doesn't work - it does when disabling it.
how do I need to configure the firewall to have it active AND working with VPN?

I checked the rules, Teamviewer seemed to have added them and they all are set to allow.